# Fabric/Crashlytics - No data and crash reports for iOS

Tags: ios, crash-reports, crashlytics, twitter-fabric

I followed all the Fabric documentation concerning crash reports for iOS.

I can see my first crash test on the dashboard, but now the App is on the AppStore, and I see no crashes, no active users, no data at all on the Fabric App.

But I know there are a lot of users right now, we can see all the stats for Android.

How can we make this solution working for iOS ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you might want to check 3 things:

[missing dYSIM](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BetbI.png)

[runscript](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mo5eW.png)

[plist](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J8ZYx.png)

Comment: No everything is setup properly

Comment: @BlaBla Double-check in your Build Settings that your Debug Information Format is “DWARF with dSYM File” for both Debug and Release

Comment: Debug information format is already set to DWARF with dSYM File for both Debug and Release

Comment: @BlaBla I'm not sure exactly your issue here, but you can check the plist and run script in your xcode. *please refer to my edited answer.