# Fabric not sending data to my dashboard

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, crashlytics, google-fabric

I set you on situation:

I had a project 1.8.10 Objective C App that was without Fabric Crashlytics. So, when I got control of the project they told me that Fabric was already installed. I checked and yes, everything was good. Still, we updated the app to the 1.9.10 (totally different build number) and we set the itunnes connect deployment in 7 days. At first I believed that was something of Apple, but now we are in 100% and there's no data. Actually, I can't see my new app's version (1.9.10) in Fabric's dashboard.

(https://stackoverflow.com/a/41160905/9684719)
Yes: I have checked **missing dYSIM, runscript, plist, at Debug information in my project I have DWARF with dSYM File.**

[Crashlytics not reporting crash in Release mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33404777/crashlytics-not-reporting-crash-in-release-mode/33506621#33506621)
Yes: I have my Fabric instantiation in Apps Delegate fine too.

[Fabric doesn't update my latest build version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47170401/fabric-doesnt-update-my-latest-build-version/47183107#47183107)
I can see in Itunes Connect that there is people using my app.

Comment: please include the sanitized output of debug mode: https://docs.fabric.io/apple/fabric/advanced-settings/debugging.html

Comment: Have you seen any "Missing DYSM Symbol" type message in Fabric dashboard

Comment: As you can see, there is no Missing DYSM Symbol in my Fabric dashboard.